# How do I make Caja preserve template text inside a script tag?

Tags: google-apps-script, handlebars.js, google-caja, icanhaz.js

I was trying to see if I could use [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for building the sidebar of my Google Docs Add-on. However, it turns out Caja is stripping the actual HTML from my script tag. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Let's just say my Handlebars template would be this:

```
<script id="user" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <li>
    <p class="name">Hello I'm {{ name }}</p>
  </li>
</script>
```

Then currently, at runtime it's this:

```
<script id="user-caja-guest-0___" data-caja-type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>
```

So, even though I'm able to look it up using `$('#user").html()`, it will just give me an empty template. Is there a  way to prevent Caja from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caja does not currently support preserving the content of `<script>` elements in any case, and also assumes that all script text is JavaScript. This would be possible, but nontrivial to support. If you need this feature, please [file a request for it](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work for Handlebars.js with Caja.

Template markup (No script tag + hiding the div)

```
<div id="entry-template" class="header" style="display: none">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your script

```
var source = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
alert(template(context));
```

And we get

```
<h1>My New Post</h1>
<div class="body">
  This is my first post!
</div>
```